# How to Mange twitter followers with Deactivated Account?

Tags: twitter

I have a lot of Twitter follower but found that many of them are deactivated. Is there any way to get rid of deactivated accounts of followers on Twitter.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a lot of [Twitter unfollower tools](https://www.easkme.com/2014/11/5-free-twitter-unfollow-tools-to.html) that can help you find deactivated accounts. But you can only remove those accounts if they get activated again.

Such as:
[unfollowerstats.com](https://unfollowerstats.com)
[Iunfollow.com](https://Iunfollow.com)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I see some of these tools are paid. But will work.